# Infinite loop when trying to work with linked lists

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, infinite-loop

I'm just starting with C and I tried to write a simple linked list that adds integers until the number is 0, however I keeping getting an infinite loop with the last number I put on the list.
I know it's probably because the last element isn't pointing to null, but I can't seem to fix it.

Thank you :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main () {
    struct nodo { 
        int num;
        struct nodo *sig;
    };
    nodo *l;
    nodo *aux;
    l=nullptr;
    int elem;
    scanf("%d", &elem);
    while (elem!=0) {
        aux->num=elem;
        aux->sig=l;
        l=aux;
        scanf("%d", &elem);
    }
    while (l!=nullptr) { 
        printf("%d", l->num);
        l=l->sig;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you set the `aux` pointer to point to anything. You don't initialize it.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note, other compilers use different options to perform the same actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that before trying to understand linked list, you should work on understanding pointers and dynamic allocation, as linked lists uses these two notions.

A linked list is a list of memory areas you have to allocate ( and dynamically ), I don't know what your program is doing here, but it should not be stable on a system with any kind of memory protection.

"aux" is a pointer wich points ... Somewhere. We don't know where, but probably not where it should.

In C, there is no magic stuff like in higher level languages ( python, etc ). You have to build your linked list by yourself

Comment: Thank you! Fixed it using aux=(nodo*) malloc(sizeof(nodo)) inside the while loop :-)

Answer (score 0):

You don't allocate any memory so `aux` isn't pointing to anything. If you initialized it at least, `nodo *aux = nullptr;`, you would at least be lucky enough to see a segfault. Beyond that, you never allocate another `aux` or `l`, so it's quite clear that the line `l=aux; ..., aux->sig=l` just makes `aux` a length-1 cyclic list, pointing to itself.